# Delay in destruction of box2d body.(cocos2d-iphone)

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I just encountered this problem where I have a box2d body collide with another box2d body and one of the bodies on collision is supposed to be destroyed. The sprite gets removed all right and the body also gets destroyed but only after approximately 4 seconds.

Please if anyone has come across this type of problem I should be grateful if you could help me out on how to solve this riddle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to destroy the b2Body immediately.

It is incorrect to try and delete bodies during collision code as the collision would also be removed.

Instead, try queuing the body for deletion and delete it on your next update loop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the body gets deleted allright but my problem is that it is supposed to be like a coins that gives the player an extra life thus on collision it is expected that it will be removed instantly but while the sprite is removed the box2d body still stays on for say 4 seconds before it gets destroyed. My problem is why the 4 seconds delay?